# How to run function before running other?

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

Hey there i m trying to post a data to my rest api so the idea is to upload the picture to the firebase storage then get the link of the picture uploaded then excute the function that post to my RESTAPI

The POST method

```
fun addItem(imageUri: Uri, title: String, description: String) {

        isItemAdditionFinished.value = false
        runBlocking {
            Log.d(PACKAGE_NAME_LOG,"Blocking cuntion")
            uploadPicture(imageUri)
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (repository.addItem(title, description, imageUrl.value).code() == 201) {
                Log.d(PACKAGE_NAME_LOG, isItemAdditionFinished.toString())
                isItemAdditionFinished.value = true

            }
        }
    }
```

the upload picture function to firebase

```
fun uploadPicture(imageUri: Uri) {
        val imageName = storageReference.child("image" + imageUri.pathSegments)
        imageName.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {
            imageName.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(PACKAGE_NAME_LOG, it.toString())
                imageUrl.value = it.toString()
            }

        }
    }
```

the runblocking didn't work and the rest api save the title and description value only
i want it to wait until the pictue uploaded then post it

Answer (score 0):

For `runBlocking` to work(e.g block the execution). You need to have a suspending function inside it.

At the moment you're just calling a normal function which does not suspend the coroutine.

So, Instead of `fun uploadPicture` you need to have `suspend fun uploadPicture`.

This should work.

Apart from that if you next function depends on the result of the first function. I'll suggest you use `async/await` for more cleaner code.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/kotlin-coroutines-async-await-part-3-6108bf6be5c4

https://joebirch.co/android/using-firebase-on-android-with-kotlin-coroutines/